# Geting untruncated data in before insert trigger event

Tags: mysql

I have a database table A with a field varchar(20). I have another table B with a field varchar(60). Insert statement is executed with character count greater than 20. I tried to setup a before insert trigger on table A and add original value (may be greater than 20) to Table B. But even in the before insert trigger, I get the truncated value (just first 20 characters). Is there any way I can add value greater than 20 characters in table B and have first 20 characters in table A.

- Table A cannot be altered to varchar(60)
- Data cannot be inserted to Table B directly (only trigger)

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to add separate column to the table A. So you will have column1 varchar(60), and column1_short(20) and use in trigger column1 to propagate data to table B.
In my opinion you cannot get value in insert trigger from original inserted value, you just have access to NEW which has changed values.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I cannot alter the table. Nor 2 insert statements.
There are several reasons that I am unable to proceed with either of these solutions

Comment: In my opinion you cannot get value in insert trigger from original inserted value, you just have access to NEW which has changed values. You should find another way to do it.